# Android integrate Play Store + Firebase logging user in

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-play

I am very stuck on the logging in part and I cannot figure out how to make it work.

I've tried to follow along with the Firebase + Android guides for how to set it up, and it seems to be partly working. When I start the project now I get a popup in the top that shows the typical google play sign in popup showing my level and an icon. (Guides are https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin + https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/play-games)

However, if I do a call to GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context) this returns as null, which means that I am logged out since I'm not getting a user back? But if I am logged out, why do I get the "logged in message" from Google Play in the top?

I have tried two different ways to sign in, but I haven't gotten any of them to actually work.

One way was to add a listener to isAuthenticated. Here I get true back, so it seems I am authenticated, but then if I try to fetch the last signed in account that is still null, and I need the signed in account so I can use that information to connect to Firebase.

```
gamesSignInClient.isAuthenticated.addOnCompleteListener { isAuthenticatedTask: Task<AuthenticationResult> ->

    val isAuthenticated = isAuthenticatedTask.isSuccessful && isAuthenticatedTask.result.isAuthenticated
    if (isAuthenticated) {

        val acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)
        if (acct != null) {
            val personName = acct.displayName
            val personGivenName = acct.givenName
            val personFamilyName = acct.familyName
            val personEmail = acct.email
            val personId = acct.id
            val personPhoto = acct.photoUrl
        }

       // firebaseAuthWithPlayGames(user!!)

        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({ continueStuff() }, 3500)
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Failed to log in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        binding.splashPbar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        binding.splashLoginButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

The second way I've tried always returns with a Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED

```
private fun promptSignIn() {

    mAuth = Firebase.auth
    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
        .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
        .build()
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

    bindingSigning.splashLoginButton.setOnClickListener {
        showLoading()
        signIn.launch(mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent)
    }
    promptSignIn()
}

private val signIn = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val data: Intent? = result.data
        val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        handleSignInResult(task)
    }
    else {
        hideLoading()
    }
}
```

I double and triple checked the values I use to connect to Play and Firebase, and I can't find any issues there. The value in string.default_web_client_id is fetched from: Play Store -> Play services -> configuration -> Web application configuration -> OAuth-client-ID Which is the same as the Client ID I find in Credentials for the project on console.cloud.google.com

Edit:
It looks like DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN is part of the problem, since I get CANCELLED when I use that, but not when I use DEFAULT_SIGN_IN

Comment: I cannot see the issue at first glance, but since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).